# What are the guidelines for assigning/mapping hotkeys in MacOS for a software engineer?

Tags: macos, keyboard, shortcut

Been coding using Mac, and code on Visual Studios Code for 5+ years, I find myself conflicting myself on assigning hotkeys. Is there a guide that analyzes what are the best methodical approach to using hotkeys? E.g.

- <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>key</kbd> to application specific
- <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>key</kbd> to the reverse effect of above etc.

I am looking for any guide that proves a good point.

Comment: Are you referencing hotkeys/shortcuts from a developer or an end user point of view?  If it's for the end user, Apple has [Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/macos/user-interaction/keyboard/) for this.  Basically, stay consistent, enable for expected things, don't over-ride the standard things, and only define them for things people do regularly.  After that, it's a dev question and most likely very opinionated (meaning off topic for this site)

Comment: @Allan https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/381597/revisions guess I messed up

Comment: @ankii - I must be missing something...not understanding what you're saying.

Comment: @Allan I misunderstood the question and now the title and body mismatch. Maybe OP is asking the best set of shortcuts which increase productivity of a software developer. But I wrote title as apple's guidelines about shortcuts that developers ship in their apps, which was on my mind for some days

Comment: @ankii - I almost made the same mistake which is why I wrote the comment instead.   If it's "productivity as a dev" then it's possibly opinionated but maybe there's a guide or a point toward emacs keybindings.  If it's from an end user usage perspective, then my comment fits with HID, but after that what works for the end user would definitely be opinionated and fall under software development.